Solving PDE using the characteritics method
I want to solve the partial differential equation
$$u_x +\frac{x}{y}[1-(x^2-y^2)(f y^2 + 2g)]u_{y}=h, $$
where f,  g, h are the real functions of x.
My artempt:
$$\frac{dx}{1}=  \frac{dy}{\frac{x}{y}[1-(x^2-y^2)(f y^2 + 2g)]}= \frac{du}{h}. $$
From
$$\frac{dx}{1}=  \frac{dy}{\frac{x}{y}[1-(x^2-y^2)(f y^2 + 2g)]}$$
we get
$$\frac{d(x^2- y^2)}{dx}= 2x- 2y \frac{dy}{dx}= 2x(x^2-y^2)(f y^2 + 2g). $$
putting $w = x^2- y^2$,  we get the Bernoulli equation as follows
$$\frac{dw}{dx}- 2x(2g + f x^2) w =-2xf w^2.$$
Solving the above equation we obtain
$$\frac{1}{w} e^{\int 2x(2g+ f x^2)dx}- \int 2xf e^{\int 2x(2g+ f x^2)dx}= c_0.$$
We can also see that
$$\frac{d (x^2- y^2)}{2x(x^2- y^2)(f y^2 + 2g)}=  \frac{du}{h}, $$
that means
$$\frac{du}{h}= \frac{dw}{2xw(f (x^2-w)+ 2g)}$$
I don't know that the above solution is correct?   If so,  how can I complete that?
Thanks for any help.
